# Any working C# code to get Google Page Rank for url containing '&' character?

Tags: c#, .net, url, pagerank

Any C# solutions i tried failed on this url - http://www.streetmap.co.uk/newmap.srf?x=529725&y=182411&z=0&sv=WC1H%2B0BX&st=2&pc=WC1H%2B0BX&mapp=newmap.srf&searchp=newsearch.srf.

Because of '&' character. Is there any C# code that handles such urls in correct way?

UPD. [Here](http://pastebin.com/L9Z2zjef) is the solution

Comment: Have you tried using URL encoding?

Comment: Yes, HttpUtility.UrlEncode before passing url to PR checker.

Comment: How are you passing the URL to the "PR checker"? Please provide more info about it.

Comment: string url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(%url%); 
string pr = GooglePageRank.GetGooglePageRank(url);

Comment: What does `GooglePageRank.GetGooglePageRank()` return?

Comment: I used different implementations, so it may return any value indicating that error occured. In all those implementations Google returns 403 HTTP error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to encode the url using:

```
var safeUrl = HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode("http://google.com?q=hello&x=123");
```

Comment: It's desktop app, so i'm using HttpUtility.UrlEncode, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code **403** stands for "Forbidden". You should verify your checksum;

> The trick to request the Google PageRank is to calculate the proper checksum of the given URL. Without the "google checksum" of the URL, you'll get a 403 Forbidden error.
>   [Source](http://www.vcskicks.com/google-pagerank.php)

Comment: Well, as you might see that's what my question is all about. Checksum is incorrect because of '&' in url. Do you know how to calculate it right?

Comment: Where did you download the lib. you´re using and does it contain any API documentation? You should most likely calculate the checksum using the raw URL, that´s before it´s encoded.

Comment: No libs or dlls. There are several code samples in the Internet.